# I just paid off my car - should I release my Credit Union's lien on the car?

Tags: united-states, car, auto-loan, new-york

We just came upon a windfall significant enough to pay off our car loan - so I did.  My Credit Union just sent me a letter describing the way in which I can remove them from the lien.  From the letter:

> If you wish to remove (credit union) as the lien holder from your vehicle/boat title, send this original lien release, the original certificate of title, a $20 check or money order, and a completed MV-902 to the NYS Dept of Motor Vehicles...
>
> ...If you choose not to remove (credit union) as a lien older, it is important that you retain this original lien release...

This being my first car, I wasn't actually prepared to make this decision - so I'd like to know, what are the consequences of removing/not removing the credit union as a lien holder, assuming I want to continue driving my car for awhile and not sell it right away?

Comment: One potential benefit (unsure on details, so a comment): I believe the lien would prevent a type of identity theft where a loan is taken against the vehicle without your consent.  An existing lien on the vehicle would make this more difficult to do.

Comment: Would the car be cross-collateral for any other accounts with the credit union? Perhaps removing the lien would eliminate the potential for repossession should things go south in the future?

Comment: I don't see why you're asking about *"removing the credit union as a lien holder"* as distinct to *"paying off the loan"*, unless that's what you mean. In the US, making regular payments on a loan (regardless of its size) us. boosts your credit rating, esp. if you're a renter and have no other loan/mortgage, so you might want to consider that. Or you could refi the auto loan down to a lower rate (/shorter term) and part-pay-down the loan, e.g. $5000 @ 4% for 24 mths instead of $20000 @ 8% for 48 mths, and then you essentially get the best of both worlds. It depends on your financial scenario

Comment: @smci My financial situation is I have already paid off the loan because I want to put that money into savings and investments each month instead of sinking it into a loan.  I have already done that and received a letter from the Credit Union informing me that their lien on the title of the car should be released.  So I am asking if there is any reason *not* to do this.

Comment: In my state (MI), you do not need anything other than a release of lien to transfer title to a new owner. I've financed many cars through credit unions and banks and *never* bothered to get a so-called 'clean' title. If NY is the same, send a copy of the release of lien to your insurance company, clip it to your (formerly encumbered) title and forget about it.

Comment: In some states it's the duty of the lender to remove the lean and send you the title.  I live in Calif, and last time I made the last payment on a car loan, the title showed up in the mail with my name on it without my doing anything.  I would challenge the Credit Union.  Banks & credit unions in US often try things which are legal in one state but illegal in your state and will back down if you challenge them.

Comment: "send [...] the original certificate of title" - Why would you do that? If you have a title, you can sell the car, no?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For practical purposes, you will need/want to remove the lien before you sell the car<sup>**1**</sup>, so unless you plan to run the car until it falls apart<sup>**2**</sup>, you will need to remove it at some point. The question then becomes: do I remove it *now*, or wait until later?

I've not been able to find any reason why keeping the lien attached to the car's title would be beneficial: Experian's article [**What to Do Once You Pay Off Your Car**](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/i-paid-my-car-loan-now-what/) starts:

> **Get Your Car Title**
>
> You just paid off your car and own it outright—now get the paperwork that says so. Your car title is a piece of paper that lists the official owner and any lien holders on your car.

before going on to discuss the differences between title-holding states and non-title-holding states. In either case it continues:

> Once you receive either of these documents, follow your state's protocol for transferring the title to your name. This will allow you to show ownership and sell the car in the future, so get all this paperwork in order as soon as possible.

(*It also notes that you may get a better rate on your insurance, backing up [Kwadzo's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/128256/35567)*).

What it does **not** give is any reason for **not** removing the lien, or for waiting to remove it, and neither does any other site I've found.

With that in mind, the only half-plausible reason I can think of to *not* remove the lien straightaway is to "*not have to fork out $20*" (at least for the time being). However, although I've no experience with any of America's Departments of Motor Vehicles, the experience I *do* have has taught me that such fees *almost never get reduced*. If you leave the lien in place "*to save $20 today*", then by the time you come to sell in a few years time, it may very well cost $24 to remove the lien from the title.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> According to Credit Karma's article [How to sell a car with a lien](https://www.creditkarma.com/auto/i/sell-car-with-lien), it's *possible* to sell with a lien attached, but is much more hassle.

<sup>**2**</sup> According to [Loren Pechtel's comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/1884/loren-pechtel), you still need "clear title" if you want to junk an old car. This is generally confirmed by a *Junk Car Medics* article [**5 Things to Do Before You Junk Your Car for Cash to an Auto Junk Yard**](https://www.junkcarmedics.com/blog/before-junk-your-car/):

> **2.  Get Your Title In Order**
>
> You need to return license plates and cancel your insurance. The single most important thing you need in order to [transfer ownership of your vehicle](https://www.junkcarmedics.com/transfer-car-title/) to the junkyard is a valid title to the car.  You can [sell your car without a title](https://www.junkcarmedics.com/blog/sell-car-without-title/) but it’s much harder.

While acknowledging it's *possible* to sell a car without a title (although that mostly seems to be for cases where the title document has been lost), it *does* also go on to say (after noting that you should "*be especially wary of a junkyard that doesn’t care if you have a title in hand*"):

> The only exception for the need to produce a valid title is if the state where you live in puts a limit on the need for a title if the car is over a certain age. You’ll still need to produce valid picture ID for the transaction to be legal. This exception is usually made because some abandoned cars might have been left for years in remote locations, and the property owners can find no paperwork for them. In any case, it’s smart to inquire with the local department of motor vehicles if you’re not sure of the regulations regarding sales to junkyards and scrap yards.

So there *may* be situations where not removing the lien isn't a problem, but overall, as noted elsewhere in comments, the OP's best course is probably to hang on to the paperwork until Covid restrictions ease sufficiently for them to print out the necessary forms and pay the $20 to have the lien removed.

Comment: It's a great question, why the heck would you "not want to" remove it?  I wonder if there's some legal comeback or something .. IDK

Comment: Honestly the real inconvenience here is needing to print out the MV-902 and scan the Lien letter to keep as a business copy - I haven't had to have a printer in 8 years (my work lets me use the printer there) and there aren't any libraries open in my area.  So my best bet if I don't want to shell out cash for a new printer would be spending an hour or so at the local Staples to put together the documentation.  That being said, if the insurance premium *could* go down because of it, then it might be worth my time.

Comment: @Zibbobz You *might* be able to do it online here: https://transact2.dmv.ny.gov/titleduplicate/?_ga=2.120491656.1680988652.1595943220-1239536868.1595943220

Comment: @Kevin This looks like a site for replacing a lost Title Certificate - not for requesting that a third party be removed from an existing one.

Comment: @Zibbobz I wasn't sure.  The form they told you to use has a similar title (APPLICATION FOR DUPLICATE TITLE), so I wasn't sure. Not having a car registered in NY, I couldn't get far enough in the online process to see if it would work for what you need

Comment: @Zibbobz You just said your work lets you use their printer, so there is your answer...

Comment: @user253751 In case you didn't know this, there's a bit of a pandemic going on right now - I haven't been able to get to the office for a few months now.

Comment: @Zibbobz Really? VPN, print to office printer, ask colleague on-site to pick up the copy and snail-mail it back to you. Unless the office is totally closed obviously. In that case: Print to PDF, email to colleague/family member/friend that has printer and ask them to print it and snail-mail back to you. Or just walk over to a neighbour that has printer.

Comment: Or just keep the lien until the office is open again and do it then

Comment: @Christian That is probably what I will wind up doing - it doesn't sound like there's any danger in waiting, and I know we're supposed to be opening up again partially at the end of August, so I can wait until that time.

Comment: Or ask the lienholder for a second copy of the release letter.

Comment: As somebody who forgot to release the lien on one of his cars until he attempted to trade it in, it's much less of a headache to deal with it now than later. Then, if you lose the title, all you've got to do is apply for a duplicate title, instead of get a duplicate copy of the letter from the lienholder, release the lien, and then sell the car (which can take weeks, total; fortunately we didn't need the trade-in value of the car).

Comment: Even if you drive it until it falls apart you need the title to sell it to the junk yard.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Thanks for that info: I've added a footnote about it.

Comment: "If you wish to remove (credit union) as the lien holder from your vehicle/boat title, **send** this original lien release, **the original certificate of title**" - If you *have* a title for the car to send them, why are you doing anything?

Answer (score 13):

When I paid off the loan, I wanted to get the lender off the title.  It streamlines the transfer of title when you are selling the car.

Some answers have said that it can save you money on insurance. I think that is only true if you were keeping specific levels of coverage because the lender required you to have that particular coverage, and you will be lowering or eliminating that part of the policy. But you can do that without having to pay $20 to the state for the new title.

One thing you want to do is to let the insurance company know that the loan has been paid off. This isn't to save money, it is to make sure that the insurance company doesn't notify the lender if the vehicle is damaged.

Normally when you have a loan the insurance company will notify the lender of the claim  because the lender has a monetary interest in having you get the repair. It protects their collateral. In some cases the settlement check is made out to the owner and the lender. If they are no longer the lender you will need to get the check reissued.

Sometimes the insurance company will also send proof of insurance to the lender, notifying them that the loan has been paid off will eliminate this notification.

Answer (score 9):

A co-worker of mine paid off his car, got the lien release and then moved. During the move, he lost his copy of the letter. In the mean time, the place he purchased his car from had gone out of business. Since the paper title had a lien holder on it, and there was no way to verify that the lien was paid off, he could not sell his car and the new state would have mailed the paper title to the defunct car dealership.

While New York state participates in an electronic lien system, based on that letter, your lender does not participate in the program. If they had participated, they could release the lien and the NY state computer system would show that the lien was gone - you would not need to worry about the paper title (or even losing it).

Comment: I think this is the most important factor. If you don't release the lien now, you will need the lienholder's consent later to sell the car. If you have lost the letter -- and how sure are you that you can keep track of it for the life of the car? -- you will be up shit creek if the lienholder is bankrupt/unhelpful/has lost their own records in the meantime.

Comment: (Or to put it another way: Think of a lien as an "asterisk" on ownership of property. Do you really want your ownership of the car to have a little asterisk on it, for the lifetime of the car, that says "*not full ownership, but subject to approval of [Credit Union]?" And your only defense against that is a letter sitting in a drawer somewhere saying "actually no, we're all good, signed [Credit Union]"? Better to just get the asterisk removed.)

Comment: Boils down to how good you are at keeping important papers. Can you find your Social Security card? Birth certificate? Marriage certificate? Deed?  If you're the kind of person who considers those trash, then maybe pay the $20 to have the asterisk removed.

Answer (score 7):

If you were to ever lose the title and lien release or have them accidentally destroyed (fire, flood), then you have both the state and credit union to deal with to get replacements, instead of just the state, unless you had already removed the lien.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the details of NEW YORK lien holder law, it should help reduce your insurance premiums once the car becomes yours with your name on the title. You may also be able to reduce the insurance coverage you currently are obligated to carry on the vehicle by your lien holder. I will say go for it. Why drive around with someone else's name on your property?